Categorical variable explained by two numeric variables - which methods are appropriate?
I have the following situation:
I have a list of patients, which have been given two medications, medication A and medication B, both numeric, as count of prescriptions, and a record of their healing success, as categorical variable, "healed"/"not healed". Some patients have only been given medication A, some only medication B and then others have been given both medications.
My goal now is to analyze, which medication has positive effect on the healing, considering possible interactions between two medications. I am thinking to perform a logistic regression. But wondering if there is any other useful method which I should consider?
Thanks in advance

Logistic reg. sounds right to me, at least to start with.
But you need to think about how you want to deal with your IVs.
First, count variables are interesting. They are not continuous (you can't have a fractional scrip). Are all scrips the same? For many drugs, there are different dosages. You might want to convert to unit/day (where unit is mg, or mcg, or whatever is appropriate).
Second, there is very likely a non-linear relationship, so you might want to use splines of dosage. Frank Harrell has some excellent R code for this. In particular, I'd guess that going from none to any is going to be a lot different than other changes.
You can also look at interactions between the splines.
Finally, you will surely want other covariates, even if there was random assignment, but especially if assignment was not and, if your data come from different doctors, hospitals, or whatever, you may need to account for non-independent errors. One way to do this is a nonlinear multilevel model.
